# Solidity v0.6.0. Fallback функции. Зачем они нужны?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract

После прочтения документации по Solidity v0.6.0 [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/060-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes), я так и не понял смысл `fallback` функций. Прочитал, что она была разделена на 2 функции: `fallback() external payable` и `receive() external payable`. Что они анонимны, и не принимают никаких параметров и подавляющем большинстве случаев для получения средств используется `receive() external payable`. Можете плз обьяснить на примере моего кода, какие-то юзабельные кейсы для этих функций, чтобы понять все их плюшки, а то как-то все в вакууме, но понимаю что это важный концепт. Не понятен даже смысл функции `receive() external payable` в которой я стучусь к методу `buyToken()`, зачем она нужна, если я в `Remix` стучусь к `buyToken()` напрямую, минуя `receive() external payable` так как она не видна и анонимна.

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract BuyToken {
  mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
  address payable wallet;

  event Purchase(
    address indexed buyer,
    uint256 amount
  );

  constructor(address payable _wallet) {
    wallet = _wallet;
  }


  fallback() external payable {
  }


  receive() external payable {
    buyToken();
  }

  function buyToken() public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] += 1;
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    emit Purchase(msg.sender, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю обе функции "маскируют" вызов метода, который в смарт-контракте не описан: receive - для случая, когда в транзакции передается value, fallback - когда нет. Наличие этих функций исключает откат транзакции, если в ней указан несуществующий метод смарт-контракта.

Зачем это нужно? Вот прям сразу не придумаю. Ну, например, переводить на адрес смарт-контракта без указания метода.

Answer (score 0):

receive выполняется когда на контракт падает эфир, в данном случае при поступлении эфира на контракт выполняется функция buyToken();

fallback определена пустой для защиты от атаки reentrance